# Is it possible to import an MX file without evaluating the contents?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**Question:** Is it possible to import an MX file saved using `DumpSave` without evaluating the contents?

---

**Let me illustrate:**

Let's create a variable, `data`:

```
In[2]:= data = Range[10]

Out[2]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

It can be exported to and imported from MX without making any definitions:

```
In[3]:= ImportString@ExportString[data, "MX"]

Out[3]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

But what if we use `DumpSave`?

```
In[4]:= DumpSave["data.mx", data]

Out[4]= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

(And clear `data`)

```
In[5]:= Clear[data]
```

On re-import, nothing is returned:

```
In[6]:= Import["data.mx", {"MX", "HeldExpression"}]
```

But the variable `data` becomes defined again, as if we had used `Get`.

```
In[7]:= data

Out[7]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I would have expected to get something like `Hold[data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]`, i.e. something similar to what would be written to an `.m` file when using `Save`.

---

Perhaps it's technically impossible to avoid the definition being made because `DumpSave` and `Get` directly manipulate the kernel state instead of writing and reading an evaluatable definition like `Save` does?  This is just a guess.

---

**(edit) please note:** I am not trying to save in a way that can be imported "Held".  I can already do that using `Export`.  I am looking to import previously `DumpSave`d MX files instead.

---

**Answer** It appears it is impossible to do this unless the MX file was saved to specifically allow it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that the logic of .mx files is the inverse one: when you load an .mx file, the definitions (`DownValues` and others) for symbols are created at the lowest level, so that the values are assigned directly to the internal memory locations, by-passing the main evaluator. This is the reason why loading .mx files is so fast. It seems that you can't have both - your expectation corresponds to a higher-level symbolic code. You can, however, encapsulate your data by using symbols in some context, as handles for that data.

So, I don't see a real problem here, since you can always query the `DownValues` and other `...Values` of symbols and extract the r.h.sides of the rules in unevaluated form (there are some pathological cases for which `DownValues` don't fully reconstruct the original definitions being stored in them, but they are, so to say, of measure zero, and not much practical importance). You can define certain interface, which would allow you to extract your data via a few functions (symbols), while the data can use many more symbols under the cover, which would be hidden behind those.

*EDIT*

If you control the initial use of `DumpSave`, here is an illustration of one possibility - you can create a custom `dumpSave`-like function. These are helper function to prepare information on symbols:

```
ClearAll[dress];
dress[prop_] := 
   Function[s, With[{pr = prop[s]}, Hold[prop[s] = pr]], HoldAll]

ClearAll[getHeldProperties];
getHeldProperties[HoldComplete[s_Symbol]] :=
 Thread[
    Through[(dress /@ {
        DownValues, UpValues, OwnValues,
        SubValues, DefaultValues, NValues, 
        FormatValues, Options, Messages, 
        Attributes
      })[Unevaluated[s]]], 
    Hold];
```

for example:

```
In[284]:= 
getHeldProperties[HoldComplete[data]]

Out[284]= Hold[{DownValues[data]={},UpValues[data]={},OwnValues[data]={HoldPattern[data]:>
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},SubValues[data]={},DefaultValues[data]={},
NValues[data]={},FormatValues[data]={},Options[data]={},Messages[data]={},
Attributes[data]={}}]
```

Now, the main function:

```
ClearAll[dumpSave];
SetAttributes[dumpSave, HoldRest];
dumpSave[file_String, storage_Symbol, symbs___] :=
  Module[{n = 1},
    Replace[
      Thread[HoldComplete[{symbs}]],
      held : HoldComplete[s_] :> 
         (storage[n++] = getHeldProperties[held]), 
      {1}];
    DumpSave[file, storage]
]
```

You basically designate a single symbol as a storage of unevaluated definitions of other symbols. Here is how you can use it:

```
dumpSave["data.mx", storage, data, dumpSave, dress]
```

If you now clear the `storage` symbol and load back the file, you will observe that all definitions of other saved symbols are stored in unevaluated form in `DownValues` of `storage`. You only need to call `ReleaseHold` on them to actually execute the assignments, but you also have access to them in unevaluated form.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me point out that there appears to be an undocumented third argument for `DumpSave`. I discovered this while trolling for functions with MX in them.

See for yourself by evaluating `` ?System`Private`BuildApplicationMXFunction `` (fix those context marks--SO markup prevents using the regular symbol). Note that in the last line of the function, `HoldAllComplete` is given as a third argument.

Dunno if that will be of use or not. Regardless, here's a solution to what I think you're asking.

```
Remove[data, assignment];
assignment := (data = Range[10])
```

Depending on what you want, you might also try `assignment := Defer[(data = Range[10])]`.

Now evaluate:

```
DumpSave["data.mx", assignment, HoldAllComplete] (*Also could try Unevaluated as 3rd arg *)
Remove[data, assignment];
Import["data.mx", "HeldExpression"]
```

And note that `data` is undefined until evaluating `assignment`. If you use the `Defer` version of`assignment`,`data` will again be undefined and assignment will return (literally) `data = Range[10]` You could use `Evaluate@@assignment` to evaluate and restore the original assignment to `data`.

(*Now it's time to read Leonid's answer and see how dumb I am!!*) :D

Comment: If you enclose inline code in double backticks (\`\`) then you cab include a single backtick in it.  See my edit to your answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. Thought I had tried that. Sometimes the instant preview seems flaky. Another issue is the spacing before and after inline code. If you put a space (like one would normally do) it appears typeset as two spaces. Leave no space and it looks as it should. I use several different browsers, but Chrome most of the time.